# SQLplus Error handling for nested scripts

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

I'll try to explain the best I can.

I want to run a script through sqlplus. I know that I can use `@` or `@@` or `START`.
I also know that to stop and exit in case of errors, I can use
`WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE ROLLBACK`

What I need and I don't know is: is it possible to break the execution of a nested script in case of error, but continue in the main script? CONTINUE in the WHENEVER is not what I want. The nested script must stop processing in case of error.

It's for CI/CD automation script I'm writing.

like this:

```
SET ECHO OFF
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE ROLLBACK
START SCRIPT_WITH_ERRO.sql
PROMPT "This line should be prompted even if there was an error before"
SHOW ERRORS
```

Comment: Sorry, sqlplus is just not smart enough for that. Anything more sophisticated than just starting some SQL commands and call some scripts goes beyond its capabilities.

Comment: If you really want to add job control, you must switch to something more flexible. Either do it in PL/SQL or Perl - Each database installation and full clients bring their own Perl with an already installed DBD::Oracle.